# Solving the integral equation $y(x)=e^{-x^2/2}+\lambda\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-i(x-z)}y(z)dz$

Tags: functional-equations

Could you please help me to solve the following integral equation?

> $$y(x)=e^{-x^2/2}+\lambda\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-i(x-z)}y(z)dz$$
> I tried to turn the exponentiential term into its trigonometric form and tried to solve the equation obtain in term of new constants $c_1=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}cos(z)y(z)dz$ and $c_2=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}sinz(z)y(z)dz$. But I obtained for $c_1$
> $$c_1=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}cos(z)e^{-z^2/2}dz+\lambda (c_1+ic_2)\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}cos^2(z)dz+\lambda(c_2-c_1i)\times\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}cos(z)sinzdz.$$
> I can't go further.

I also applied the Fourier transform on both sides and obtained that this equation has a unique solution iff $$1-\lambda\hat{K}(\alpha)\neq 0$$ where $$\hat{K}(\alpha)$$ is the Fourier transform of $e^{-ix}$. But I think (I am not sure) the Fourier transform of such a function is the dirac function $\delta_{-\alpha}$, and I don't know how to proceed.

Please need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Taking, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y(z)e^{iz} =a \in \mathbb C$, we get $y(x)=e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}+\lambda ae^{-ix}$. Putting this back in the first equation we see that $a$ diverges ( if $a≠0$ ) and $a=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{e}}$ if $a=0$. So, there are no solutions (for $\lambda ≠0$).

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Very helpful!